# Communication between already existing classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am sorry if this question seems pretty basic and there is already an answer for that, but unless I make it into a proper question, google won't find it.

I have a main class that is a JFrame(there is and will be only one object, let's call it "main"), it creates and calls another JFrame class(let's call it window2), however, I still need this window2 to call methods from the already existing main class. Normally window2 would have something like     Main mainMenu = new Main();.
But this obviously creates a new object of main, I still want to refer to the already existing object and get information from it.

Comment: You should share the relevant code, but to point to the object reference of the current instance, you use the `this` keyword.

Comment: I am not too sure why you would want to get behaviours from object main if you already have behaviours from object windows 2.. it will be clear to see your code and to understand what you are trying to do..

Comment: Pass a reference of `main` to `window2`

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection. The answer depends on whether your Main class is static, but let's assume it is not:

- Create a Main reference in Window2: Main main;
- Create a method in Window2: public void injectMainInstance(Main main){this.main=main}
- In Main you have the Window2 instance window2. Call window2.injectMainInstance(this);

You should be good to go now in Window2 with main.mainMethodTBUsed();

Comment: Thank you, that worked, yes my main method is not static. I am a beginning programmer and I thought a problem might be much easier to resolve, I have never heard about dependency injection before and I am not even sure if this is a correct way to do things. But it works, thank you.